# Logrotate daily+maxsize is not rotating

Tags: centos, logrotate

I've CentOS 7.4 with logrotate 3.8.6 installed. I've a custom logrotate file under `/etc/logrotate.d/` to rotate some logs on a Tomcat (e.g., catalina.out) which is installed in the same machine.

```
/opt/test/apache-tomcat-8.5.15-client/logs/catalina.out {
copytruncate
daily
rotate 30 
olddir /opt/test/apache-tomcat-8.5.15-client/logs/backup
compress
missingok
maxsize 50M
dateext
dateformat .%Y-%m-%d
}
```

I want the log to be rotated daily or if the size reaches 50MB. When this happens log files are compressed and copied into a backup folder and are kept for 30 days before being deleted.

I already ran logrotate manually in debug mode with the following command and no errors were displayed (and the expected zipped log files were created):

`/usr/sbin/logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/openncp-tomcat-backoffice 2> /tmp/logrotate.debug`

In `/var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status` there are no issues, the files are shown as rotated but they're not in fact:

```
"/var/log/yum.log" 2017-11-27-19:0:0
"/opt/test/apache-tomcat-8.5.15-server/logs/catalina.out" 2017-12-15-3:41:1
"/var/log/boot.log" 2017-12-15-3:41:1
"/var/log/up2date" 2017-11-27-19:0:0
```

I've the default `/etc/logrotate.conf`:

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp and btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
        minsize 1M
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0600 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be also be configured here.
```

I also have the default `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status /etc/logrotate.conf
EXITVALUE=$?
if [ $EXITVALUE != 0 ]; then
    /usr/bin/logger -t logrotate "ALERT exited abnormally with [$EXITVALUE]"
fi
exit 0
```

According to the [logrotate manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/logrotate/logrotate.8.en.html):

```
maxsize size
    Log files are rotated when they grow bigger than size bytes even before the additionally specified time interval ( daily, weekly, monthly, or yearly). The related size option is similar except that it is mutually exclusive with the time interval options, and it causes log files to be rotated without regard for the last rotation time. When maxsize is used, both the size and timestamp of a log file are considered.
```

I've noticed that so far the logs have not reached 50MB, and several days have passed without any rotation.

I ask for your guidance on configuring this appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to the SELinux file type of the log files, which were located in a directory different from /var/log, meaning that the logrotate process didn't have access to perform its tasks. I found this other [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652654/logrotate-cron-job-not-rotating-certain-logs) as well as this [Redhat page](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/39006) that helped to solve the issue. I found the Redhat documentation very helpful, so I provide here 2 links:

- [5.9.3. CHECKING THE DEFAULT SELINUX CONTEXT](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-maintaining_selinux_labels_-checking_the_default_selinux_context)
- [5.6.2. PERSISTENT CHANGES: SEMANAGE FCONTEXT](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-selinux_contexts_labeling_files-persistent_changes_semanage_fcontext)